# URL redirection by checking parameter

Tags: java, filter, url-rewriting, web.xml, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I have URL like [www.mysite.com/?cmd=login&param=1](http://www.mysite.com/?cmd=login&param=1)

I would like to redirect to another link if &param=1 parameter is not present

```
<rule>
<condition type="parameter" name="param" operator="notequal"/>
<from>^/(.*)</from>
<to type="redirect>www.mysite.com/$1</to>
</rule>
```

Could someone help me out if this is the correct way